# Why isn't impress.js working when hosted on GDrive?

Tags: google-drive-api, impress.js

I recently tried to test if impress.js presentations could be hosted on Google Drive. For some reason, it isn't working. The offline copy of the file works on my computer but the hosted copy doesn't work.

I'm using Google Chrome and my OS is Windows Vista. My browser says the page has insecure content and even when I load that content, the JavaScript doesn't seem to work.

Comment: well you cant host them on google drive obviously.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've tried and it IS possible.

Here's an article from a reliable source that supports my statement:
http://lifehacker.com/5964262/host-web-pages-on-google-drive

Comment: There's a pile of 404s in the console, maybe fix them first?

Comment: Thank you David, I didn't know what a console was until you just introduced this word to me. Yes, I'm a newbie.

Comment: @Nick: Did you know that you can get a short custom URL at http://gdriv.es?

Comment: @niutech: Yes, thank you, but I don't see much use in that. I'd rather use a free domain like ".tk"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible. Check the JavaScript console to find out why it is failing for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I never knew what a JavaScript Console was until today. So, I checked it and apparently I forgot to upload the main thing... which was impress.js

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't seem to understand what your referring to. Do you mean the javascript files or the console or the presentation?